# Box2D and ARC doubts

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, box2d

I'm trying to use Box2D in ARC environment. Below is how I pass ObjC pointer to non-ObjC space using `__bridge`. But it doesn't seems to me legal, since `sprite` var can be deallocated.

```
- (void)addBoxBodyForSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite
{
    b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
    ...
    spriteBodyDef.userData = (__bridge void*)sprite;
    b2Body *spriteBody = _world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);
    ...
    spriteBody->CreateFixture(&spriteShapeDef);
}
```

This is how I transfer that same sprite from non-ObjC to ObjC space, this time using `__bridge _transfer`.

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
    ...
    CCSprite *sprite = (__bridge_transfer CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
    ...
}
```

I also deallocate use `DestroyBody(...)` to deallocate body, which contains sprite reference and not specifically deleting `userData`, because I'm assuming that body live longer than sprite.

Question is whether using the bridges above is legal or not.

Answer (score 0):

To store an Objective-C object in a stuct, use `struct.val = CFBridgingRetain(val)`. when accessing the value, use `id val = (__bridge id)struct.val`. For releasing it, use `CFRelease(struct.val)`.